# redux array, array.length is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

So in my react application i have in my store, an array of video objects `videos: [{},{}]` now im trying to work with this information, so when i load a page, obviously the array is empty,  `videos: []` because the action has yet to fire off to fetch the videos from the server. so im trying to do a bit of conditional rendering, that if videos.length > 0 do something, because for testing purposes im trying to access videos[2] which doesnt exist until the array is populated.

but im getting an error that videos.length is undefined

i destructured the state
`const {videos, loading} = useSelector(state => state.videos)` (where the reducer is also called videos..

in my Redux extension i can clearly see that its an empty array, and i know even an empty array, has a length property (0) so i dont understand why im getting this as undefined.

Comment: Where's the code?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:
`const {videos, loading} = useSelector(state => state.videos)`

assumes that `state.videos` is an object which will have 2 props `videos` and `loading`. Something like so:

```
state: {
  videos : {
    videos: videosValue
    loading: loadingValue
  }
}
```

When it finds the 2 props, then it destructures `state.videos` and assigns the values like so:
`videos = videosValue`
and
`loading = loadingValue`

You may want to review your state. May be the state does not have the structure stated above? May be `state` object has a prop named `videos` which is an Array & another prop named `loading` which is boolean?

If `state` object is of the below structure:

```
state: {
  videos: videosValue
  loading: loadingValue
}
```

then, you may want to destructure the `state` object and not `state.videos` object.

Comment: No, the state is similar ot the first setup, and it was a typo on my part to call it state.videos, but the state is of that way, there is an object that holds the two properties videos and loading, videos is indeed an array, and it holds several objects, i was able to successful map over for the purposes of displaying data from them. but even then it wont let me call .length on the array itself.. i just dont understand why.

Comment: Could you please update the question with the structure of the `state` object as well as `state.videos`? Also: if you could add a `console.log` to view the values in both `state` and `state.videos` it will help investigate further.